# i am not able to pass value from one view controller to another view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

hi i have problem that i am not able to pass value from one view controller to another view controller through button i implement when i click on button other view appear on iphone screen but the value which i have set not dispay this is the button code

```
   -(IBAction)save:(id)sender 
{ 
nextview *admin = [[nextview alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:admin animated:YES]; 
    if (admin.view)
    { 
admin.fetchname = name.text; 
} 
    [admin release];
}
```

and this is the nextview.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface nextview : UIViewController
{
    UILabel *getname;

    NSString *fetchname;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet NSString *fetchname;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *getname;

@end
```

and this is the nextview.m file

```
#import "nextview.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation nextview
@synthesize getname,fetchname;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
#pragma mark - View lifecycle




- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    getname.text = self.fetchname;



    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The viewDidLoad method is called before you had a chance to assign your NSString value.
That's why you dont see the text in your UIButton.
Try this :

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender 
{ 
    nextview *admin = [[nextview alloc] init];

    admin.fetchname = name.text; 

    [self presentModalViewController:admin animated:YES];  
    [admin release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   -(IBAction)save:(id)sender 
   { 
          nextview *admin = [[nextview alloc]init];
          [self presentModalViewController:admin animated:YES]; 
          if (admin.view)
          { 
                 admin.fetchname = name.text; 
          } 
          [admin release];
   }
```

You release the instance of nextview right after you assign the name. That can't even work.

By the way, getname and fetchname are really bad chosen names for properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.
You can implement the below code in nextView.h

```
        NSString *fetchData;
```

also property and synthesize this

```
       @property(nonatomic, retain)  NSString *fetchData;
```

implement this on button pressed code

```
         -(IBAction)save:(id)sender 
         { 
                nextview *admin = [[nextview alloc] init];

                admin.fetchData = name.text; 

                [self presentModalViewController:admin animated:YES];  
                [admin release];
          }
```